# Do calls to external functions force loads from memory?

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose we have the following C++11/14 code:

```
int* buf = ExternalFunction1();

int x = *buf;

ExternalFunction2();

int y = *buf;
```

where `ExternalFunction1()` and `ExternalFunction2()` are not known at the time the translation unit is compiled, and are possibly not even known before runtime (i.e. they come from a shared library).

Does the C++ language guarantee that the value of `y` will actually be read from `buf`, or is it possible that it is simply set to the value of `x`?

I'm interested in the guarantees offered by C++11's abstract machine, not the behavior of any particular compiler (in practice they all seem to reload the value from memory).

EDIT: Clarified sample code based on comments.

Comment: The available optimisations depend on the content of `...`

Comment: It strikes me that you've probably missed the most crucial part of your code above. Surely, it matters how `buf` is instantiated - if it points to some heap-allocated memory, then we might expect `ExternalFunction()` to modify it. If it's from the stack, it would be highly irregular for a function to read up the stack without being passed a pointer, so a compiler might reasonably assume it can optimise.

Comment: I've clarified the code, let me know if this still isn't enough to answer the question.

Comment: Well now it's easy - since we don't know what `buf` is pointing to, we can't guarantee that `ExternalFunction2` won't modify it, so we must reread from memory when assigning `y`.

Comment: @RbMm Indeed - my comment was based on a previous version of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we don't know what `buf` is pointing to, we can't guarantee that `ExternalFunction2` won't modify it, so we must reread from memory when assigning `y`.

Comment: agree with you. simply interesting are this can be formal prove by some specification, or general sense enough here